# Before iron was common, what did common people use for door hinges?

Tags: everyday-life, architecture

Door hinges are very old, but they've usually been made out of iron or bronze.  Before metal was widely available and inexpensive, what did common people use for door hinges?

Comment: Leather was common as a hinge.

Comment: Also to consider: many openings had flaps of fabric or other flexible materials rather than solid doors (hinges irrelevant).

Comment: @bgwiehle, I'm specifically interested in doors, not flaps.

Comment: Leather seems to be most common. But wooden hinges are also usable.

Comment: Wigwams and tipis generally had hide 'doors', no hinges involved

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace if you have no iron, you have no nails. How will you attach the leather strip to the door and to the frame so that the door won't fall off, without nails? I am afraid, the leather worked in the times, where the iron was common, but the **steel** hinges - not.

Comment: Copper nails, bronze nails, even wooden nails - or you can tie the leather to the door.  Heck, you can even use stone shims.  People built things for thousands of years before they learned to smelt iron.

Comment: Richard Proenneke makes a great modern day example if you want to watch his documentary.  The door of his cabin (and the wooden hinges) are [visible in this photograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Proenneke#/media/File:Proenneke_Cabin_NPS.jpg).

Answer (score 13):

Apart from leather hinges that were used even when iron was common (but not so common as to be cheap), there existed the different mounting of the door. I have heard about its use from my grandfather, when I asked for explanation about what is the "heel" of the door in Russian fairy-tales.

The whole side of the door frame worked as a huge hinge - this side was made of a bit longer piece of wood, that fitted into shallow holes in the appropriate places in the outer frame. The sticking out pieces were called "heels". They are mentioned by several Russian fairy-tales, when a Door asks a hero to grease her heels. (The good hero does and gets some help).

Obviously, the very thick and heavy wooden doors of the old Russian houses simply could not be held by leather strips. (The boards were extremely expensive). And the leather had yet to be attached to the door somehow, too.

Comment: Now I'm really glad I asked this question -- I'd never heard of doors like this before!

Comment: I have only heard about them and never saw them myself. I suppose that mount could be used in the wooden architecture of the Russian North, Kizhi and around it. Maybe, somebody was there? ... A very interesting question it is. This is the real history - not wars and kings.

Comment: I had to read this several times in order to picture it in my mind's eye, but wow! Cool door!